# Emacs: what is this info returned after a variable's value?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use `eval-expression` (<kbd>M-:</kbd>) to get some variable's value in the message buffer.

I used it today to evaluate the variable `left-margin` and got the following value:

```
0 (#o0, #x0)
```

0 is the actual value, but I'm oblivious to what the other symbols mean.

If I evaluate the following with `eval-last-sexp` (<kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>) I just get the value alone:

```
(identity left-margin)
-> 0
```

Can someone shed some light on what those symbols mean and why they appear only with `eval-expression`? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the octal and hexadecimal representation of 0. The prefix `#o` means "octal representation follows" and `#x` means "hexadecimal representation follows".

To verify, do `set-variable` to e.g `10` first and then you'll get:

```
10 (#o12, #xa)
```

`a` is 10 in hex, and `12` is 10 in octal form.

Comment: ha, I expected it to be something simple like this. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can use these representations directly in elisp. See `C-h i g` `(elisp) Integer Basics` `RET` for more details.